# How to break CountDownTimer

Tags: android, timer, countdowntimer

I'm a newbie in android and I'm stucked in a problem.

**Here is my problem:** I am running a `CountDownTimer` for 30s with 5s interval. While it runs, I do an activity for each interval. If the activity returns positive result, I'll stop the timer. If timer ends, I will announce it as a failure. I tried a lot ways but I can't accomplish what I need.

I don't know how to use `CountDownTimer` or `Timer`? Perhaps you do?

Here is my code:

```
    public void StartTimeOutTimer() {
    countDown timer = new countDown(30000, 5000);
    timer.start();
    }

    public class countDown extends CountDownTimer{
    ProgressDialog pd;

    public countDown(long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval) {
        super(millisInFuture, countDownInterval);
        pd = ProgressDialog.show(Activity_MapMain.this, "",
                "Loading new location...", true, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                     //Do an activity get new location
                     //if OK stop CountDownTimer ; 
    }

    @Override
    public void onFinish() {
        pd.cancel();
    }
   }
```

Comment: Call this method "cancel()" to stop timer.

Comment: Probably won't help because it need to be called outside that class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use Handler instead. SomeThing like that:

```
Handler handler;
boolean result;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);
    handler = new Handler();
    handler.post(timerRunnable);
}


Runnable timerRunnable = new Runnable() {
    int interval = 5000, period = 30000;
    int count;
    @Override
    public void run() {
        if (!result && count < period ) {
            count += interval;
            //call to the  activity get new location with startActivityForResult()
            handler.postDelayed(this, interval);
        }
    }
};



@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK){
       result = true;
    }
}
```

**Edit**
How to start Activity for result:

First define filed:

```
private final int CODE_NEW_LOCATION = 1;
```

Inside the Rubbable put something like this:

```
 startActivityForResult(new Intent(MainActivity.this, LocationActivity.class), CODE_NEW_LOCATION);
```

Inside the LocationActivity you define the return value:

```
 boolean result;
 //define the result
 setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK);
```

Comment: I don't know how call the activity with startActivityForResult(), can you give me a simple example. Thank u so much!

Comment: That's great. I got it. Thanks for your support. I hope learn more from you. :)

Comment: No welcome. Accept my answer will nice thanks as well

Answer (score 0):

You can use:  `this.cancel();` in the CountDownTimer object.

Answer (score 0):

In You function onTick try checking flag (boolean stop;) and disable counter.
Example:

```
boolean stop;

@Override
    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

    if (stop) { 
       stop = false;
       cancel();
    }

}
```